# Python Gurobi setting up objective function

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I am using the following code to define the objective function:

```
objective = GBR.QUICKSUM(x[i,j] * c[i][j] for i in range(50) for j in range(50))
m.setObjective(objective)
```

However, it gives me an error stating that `name 'GBR' is not defined`.

I have imported `gurobipy` as `*`.

I had no issue with defining the variables:

```
for i in range(50):
  for j in range(50):

    x[(i,j)] = m.addVar(lb=0, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name='x_'+str(i)+'_'+str(j))
```

and the `cost function c[i][j]` is a list of costs for each link `X[i,j]`

How should I define the objective for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

'GBR' is indeed not defined, try GRB

Answer (score 1):

Gurobi's [quicksum](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/py_global_functions.html) is a global function. That means after

```
from gurobipy import *
m = Model()             # Creates a Gurobi Model object.
# ... create your variables etc here
```

you can use it with

```
m.setObjective(quicksum(x[i,j] * c[i][j] for i in range(50) for j in range(50)))
```

By the way: you could use the [addVars()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html) method instead of the two nested for-loops to create your variables.